# Run windows mobile 6.5 application on windows embedded compact 7

Tags: windows-mobile

I have developed an app for windows mobile 6.5 and it's running fine on my device (which uses windows mobile 6.5), but I tried to install it on other device that is running windows embedded compact 7.

When I run the cab file on the windows embedded compact 7 it returns "This program may not be compatible with this operating system" and I install it anyway, but when I run the app there is an error message and the app wont start.

Is there anyway I can run the app on an emulator or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Install [WinCE CAB Manager](http://de.freedownloadmanager.org/Windows-PC/WinCE-CAB-Manager.html), open up the CAB. There will be a _setup.xml file in it. You have to change the min os version to something big like "100.00". Repackage the cab. It should run fine. If you build your cab with a cab project, you can change the min os parameter in your project properties.

You could also install the cab on an old device or emulator and copy the installation files to the new device.

The above should get rid of the cab warning.

Your error message may be a problem with the application itself. You will have to debug it to see where it crashes. You have to install the device sdk provided by the manufacturer of your device to debug windows embedded compact 7 apps otherwise they wont run in Visual Studio 2008, when you only select "Windows CE device" as a target, like you could on older platforms. Also don't auto deploy the .NET CF Cabs, when you run your project. windows embedded compact 7 devices have in most of the cases an up to date .NET CF 3.5 SP2 installed and have a higher patch version.

To be able to run windows embedded compact 7 on an emulator you need an emulator image form a manufacturer or have to build your own using [Microsoft Platform Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38794). There is no such thing as microsoft provided emulator images for Windows CE.

Also posting the error message would help to find the problem.